# (Why) is udev using 4GB of memory?

Tags: swap, udev, memory-usage

I was trying to figure out why over 5 GB of swap is used when I only have a browser and a couple of smaller applications open:

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7916        4198        1368          64        2348        3211
Swap:         44998        5355       39643
```

Using the scripts from [this question on the topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71714/linux-total-swap-used-swap-used-by-processes), my total only came up to ~1300 MB. Then I noticed this `df` output:

```
$ df | grep udev
udev              4033812   4033812         0 100% /dev
```

Is udev really using 4 GB of memory that ends up in swap? Why?

Comparing to another xenial system, that one shows 0% for the udev filesystem.

Comment: This looks like something inside `/dev` is using all the RAM. First place to look is `/dev/shm` folder. There might be some files from processes and/or aborted processes.

Comment: @Thomas there are a few files there, but according to `du` they only amount to 37MB.

Comment: I was wrong. `/dev/shm` is a seperate mount point. Does this persist after a reboot? A first point to start is to search for regular files within `/dev` by `find /dev -xdev -type f`.

Comment: @Thomas, your comment was helpful, I found a directory /dev/.bootchart under which most of the usage seems to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. `/dev/shm` is a seperate mount point.

Does this persist after a reboot?

A first point to start is to search for regular files within `/dev` by

```
find /dev -xdev -type f
```

Comment: A single file in `/dev/.bootchart/log` was taking up 99% of the space.  Probably a bug with bootchart, I'll have to see if it happens again the next time I reboot.